# Black hole supernova

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon, singularities, supernova

This is a question about my intuition of black holes.

Assumption: The creation of a black hole follows the same physics as the creation of stars. A star can supernova, I'm assuming a black hole also can and that it appears frozen in our reference frame. Is this correct?

If it can supernova, what is the relationship between space, time and volume at the singularity? I don't know the math, but might there be a more general definition for volume that includes time as a component?

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated business, and your assumptions are not all correct.

A star is formed by the gravitational collapse of a very large cloud of gas and dust. When the center of that collapsing cloud gets dense enough and hot enough, it lights up as a star and begins fusing hydrogen into progressively heavier nuclei, a process which ends with iron nuclei. Extremely massive stars can over time build up a core of iron big enough that it undergoes collapse while the rest of the star is still "running", which blows it to pieces and leaves behind either a neutron star or a black hole.

As you can see, a typical black hole evolves from a supermassive star, which forms first. Ordinarily, the gravitational collapse of gas and dust cannot proceed directly to a black hole except (it is thought) in the very very early universe, but this process is not certain. At any rate, once formed, a black hole cannot subsequently blow up as a supernova.

The physics of the space inside the event horizon and surrounding the singularity is a very active field, and much has been written about it which would probably interest you and answer your questions. For non-physicists like me, the best book to read about this would be the one by Kip Thorne called *Black Holes And Time Warps*.

Comment: It might be worth talking about [black hole evaporation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation)

Comment: ...and lots of other stuff. my objective was to refer them to a book which would treat all this in good detail, as my own typing speed is rather slow.